# How to avoid C# Azure API from running out of memory for large blob uploads?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to uploading very large (>100GB) blobs to Azure using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob (9.4.2). However, it appears that  even when using the stream-based blob write API, the library will allocate memory proportional to the size of the file (a 1.2GB test file results in a 2GB process memory footprint). I need this to work in constant memory. My code is below (similar results using UploadFromFile, UploadFromStream, etc.):

```
var container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sasToken));
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test");
const int bufferSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024; // 64MB
blob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes = bufferSize;
using (var writeStream = blob.OpenWrite())
{
    using (var readStream = new FileStream(archiveFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        var bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

This behavior is pretty baffling - I can see in TaskMgr that the upload indeed starts right away, so it's not like it's buffering things up waiting to send; there is no reason why it needs to hang on to previously sent data. How does anyone use this API for non-trivial blob uploads?

Comment: I see from the memory profile that the allocations are sitting in a Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.MultiBufferMemoryStream - which seems to suggest that at least in theory it could release parts of it that are no longer needed, but doesn't.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that you should report to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [BlobStorageMultipartStreamProvider](https://gist.github.com/JamesRandall/11088079) sample, as it shows how a request stream can "forwarded" to an **Azure Blob** stream and this might reduce the amount of memory used at the server side while uploading.

Hope it helps!